# Clickhouse - join on string columns

Tags: clickhouse

I got *String* column `uin` in several tables, how do I can effectively join on `uin` these tables?

In Vertica database we use `hash(uin)` to transform string column into hash with *Int* data type - it significantly boosts efficiency in joins - could you recommend something like this? I tried `CRC32(s)` but it seems to work wrong.

Comment: it's excessive. Internally CH uses hashes for join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment the CH not very good cope with multi-joins queries (DB star-schema) and the query optimizer not good enough to rely on it completely.

So it needs to explicitly say how to 'execute' a query by using subqueries instead of joins.

Let's emulate your query:

```sql
SELECT table_01.number AS r
FROM numbers(87654321) AS table_01
  INNER JOIN numbers(7654321) AS table_02 ON (table_01.number = table_02.number)
  INNER JOIN numbers(654321) AS table_03 ON (table_02.number = table_03.number)
  INNER JOIN numbers(54321) AS table_04 ON (table_03.number = table_04.number)
ORDER BY r DESC
LIMIT 8;
/*
┌─────r─┐
│ 54320 │
│ 54319 │
│ 54318 │
│ 54317 │
│ 54316 │
│ 54315 │
│ 54314 │
│ 54313 │
└───────┘

8 rows in set. Elapsed: 4.244 sec. Processed 96.06 million rows, 768.52 MB (22.64 million rows/s., 181.10 MB/s.) 
*/
```

On my PC it takes ~4 secs. Let's rewrite it using subqueries to significantly speed it up.

```sql
SELECT number AS r
FROM numbers(87654321)
WHERE number IN (
  SELECT number 
  FROM numbers(7654321)
  WHERE number IN (
    SELECT number 
    FROM numbers(654321)
    WHERE number IN (
      SELECT number 
      FROM numbers(54321)
    )
  )
)
ORDER BY r DESC
LIMIT 8;
/*
┌─────r─┐
│ 54320 │
│ 54319 │
│ 54318 │
│ 54317 │
│ 54316 │
│ 54315 │
│ 54314 │
│ 54313 │
└───────┘

8 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.411 sec. Processed 96.06 million rows, 768.52 MB (233.50 million rows/s., 1.87 GB/s.) 
*/
```

---

There are other ways to optimize [JOIN](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/#performance):

- use [External dictionary](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2020/5/19/clickhouse-dictionaries-reloaded) to get rid of join on 'small'-table
- use [Join](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/join/) table engine
- use [ANY](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/#select-join-strictness)-strictness
- use specific settings like *join_algorithm*, *partial_merge_join_optimizations* etc

---

Some useful refs:

[Altinity webinar: Tips and tricks every ClickHouse user should know](https://youtu.be/FsVrFbcyb84?t=1915)

[Altinity webinar: Secrets of ClickHouse Query Performance](https://youtu.be/6WICfakG84c?t=1635)

---

**Answer update**:

To less storage consumption for String-column consider changing column type to [LowCardinality](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2019/3/27/low-cardinality) ([link 2](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2020/5/20/reducing-clickhouse-storage-cost-with-the-low-cardinality-type-lessons-from-an-instana-engineer)) that significantly decrease the size of a column with many duplicated elements.

Use this query to get the size of columns:

```sql
SELECT
    name AS column_name,
    formatReadableSize(data_compressed_bytes) AS data_size,
    formatReadableSize(marks_bytes) AS index_size,
    type,
    compression_codec
FROM system.columns
WHERE database = 'db_name' AND table = 'table_name'
ORDER BY data_compressed_bytes DESC
```

To get a numeric representation of a string need to use one of [hash](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/hash-functions/)-functions.

```sql
SELECT 'jsfhuhsdf', xxHash32('jsfhuhsdf'), cityHash64('jsfhuhsdf');
```

Comment: Not exactly what I asked, but thank you very much for useful links!
The question is not about join optimization in clickhouse itself, but about how I can transform string column in a number representation. Mainly I need this for less storage.
For example, I have 'jsfhuhsdf' in column, string is a heavy data comparing to integer. 
I want to join raw to another table using this id. I can use just string, but output table is 10 times heavier than if I make join on integer. I think CRC32 is a good solution, I just got error in the query, now it's working good